# Translations in Angular using i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm new on i18n, i need to translate a whole div using a single id, but I can't seem to find any guide that helps me convert any html tag to xliff.

I've seen this guide https://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/xliff-profile-html/xliff-profile-html-1.2-cd02.html yet i'm not able yet to convert anything, that's my code

```
<div i18n="@@abl1">
 <h2>hello</h2>
 <h3>how are you</h3>
</div>
```

that's what i've tried:

```
<trans-unit id="abl1" datatype="html">
 <source>
  <x id="START_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;h2&gt;"/>
   Hello
   <x id="CLOSE_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;/h2&gt;"/>
   <x id="START_TAG_H3" ctype="x-h3" equiv-text="&lt;h3&gt;"/>
    How are you?
   <x id="CLOSE_TAG_H3" ctype="x-h3" equiv-text="&lt;/h3&gt;"/>
  </source>
  <target>
   <x id="START_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;h2&gt;"/>
    Salut
   <x id="CLOSE_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;/h2&gt;"/>
   <x id="START_TAG_H3" ctype="x-h3" equiv-text="&lt;h3&gt;"/>
    Comment vas tu?
   <x id="CLOSE_TAG_H3" ctype="x-h3" equiv-text="&lt;/h3&gt;"/>
  </target>
  <context-group purpose="location">
  <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/propos/propos.component.html 
  </context>
 </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

when i've tried this method with span and strong it worked just fine yet when i use it with h2 and h3 i get the following error:

```
ERROR in Unknown placeholder "START_TAG_H2" (" [ERROR ->]
<x id="START_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;h2&gt;"/>
Salut
<x id="CLOSE_"): i18n@1:10
Unknown placeholder "CLOSE_TAG_H2" (" 
<x id="START_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;h2&gt;"/>
Salut
[ERROR ->]<x id="CLOSE_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;/h2&gt;"/>
<x id="START_TAG_H3" ctype="x-"): i18n@3:10
Unknown placeholder "START_TAG_H3" ("
Salut<x id="CLOSE_TAG_H2" ctype="x-h2" equiv-text="&lt;/h2&gt;"/>
[ERROR ->]<x id="START_TAG_H3" ctype="x-h3" equiv-text="&lt;h3&gt;"/>
Comment vas tu?<x "): i18n@4:10
Unknown placeholder "CLOSE_TAG_H3" ("  
<x id="START_TAG_H3" ctype="x-h3" equiv-text="&lt;h3&gt;"/>
Comment vas tu?[ERROR ->]
<x id="CLOSE_TAG_H3" ctype="x-h3" equiv-text="&lt;/h3&gt;"/>"): i18n@6:10
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: You are better off adding the `i18n` attribute to the h2 and h3 elements

Comment: thank you, i didn't find any solution yet, so i did that